# How to fix ".map.tolist() returning an instance instead of a list" while parsing a list of maps in Flutter?

Tags: json, parsing, dart, flutter

I am trying to read a firebase realtime database and trying to convert it into a list so that I can present it in a table widget on my app.

Here is the Json data that I am importing to firebase realtime database and then calling it in my app

```
[
    {
        "SYMBOL": "VOLTAS",
        "OPEN": "572.8",
        "CLOSE": "572.2",
        "FORECAST": "TRENDING"
    },
    {
        "SYMBOL": "GODREJCP",
        "OPEN": "645.05",
        "CLOSE": "640.55",
        "FORECAST": "TRENDING"
    },
    {
        "SYMBOL": "MARICO",
        "OPEN": "355.4",
        "CLOSE": "351.4",
        "FORECAST": "TRENDING"
    },
    {
        "SYMBOL": "KOTAKBANK",
        "OPEN": "1396.0",
        "CLOSE": "1389.35",
        "FORECAST": "TRENDING"
    },
    {
        "SYMBOL": "KAJARIACER",
        "OPEN": "575.0",
        "CLOSE": "579.95",
        "FORECAST": "TRENDING"
    }
]
```

I searched for hours and hours and finally landed on this guide:
https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

I finally understood that I am dealing with a list of maps.

Below is my current set of code.
cprdata.dart:

```
class MyDataList {
  final List<MyData> myList ;

  MyDataList({
    this.myList,
  });

  factory MyDataList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {

    List<MyData> myList = new List<MyData>();
    myList = parsedJson.map((i)=> MyData.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return new MyDataList(
        myList: myList
    );
  }
}




class MyData {
  final String SYMBOL;
  final String FORECAST;
  final String OPEN;
  final String CLOSE;

  MyData({
    this.SYMBOL,
    this.OPEN,
    this.CLOSE,
    this.FORECAST});

  factory MyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    //print(json);
    return new MyData(
      SYMBOL: json['SYMBOL'],
      OPEN: json['OPEN'],
      CLOSE: json['CLOSE'],
      FORECAST: json['FORECAST']
    );
  }

}
```

cpr.dart

```
///import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'cprdata.dart';
import 'dart:convert';


class CprAnalysis extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  CPRState createState() => CPRState();
}

class CPRState extends State<CprAnalysis> {

  List<MyData> allData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseReference cprData = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

    cprData.reference().once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      var d = snap.value;
      final jsonE = json.encode(d);
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonE);
      MyDataList zz = new MyDataList.fromJson(jsonResponse);
      print(zz.myList);

      setState(() {
        print("Done");
        //print('Length : ${allData.length}');
      });
    }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("CPR Analysis"),

      ),
    );
  }
```

Expected result is a list containing the data of the json file in a list format so that I can use it to make a table to show on my app.

Actual result:

```
I/flutter (16067): [Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance of 'MyData', Instance o
I/flutter (16067): Done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking Dart to print the contents of zz which is a List of MyData instances - so it's doing the right thing. If you want to see the data contained within the list something like the following would work:

```
zz.forEach((data) => print(
      "Row contains ${data.SYMBOL} - ${data.FORECAST} - ${data.OPEN} - ${data.CLOSE}"));
```

Comment: when I tried your solution, it is throwing error.
error: The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the class 'MyDataList'.


Edit: you got my issue perfectly. I want to access the data so that I can use it for a Table widget and present it as a table.

Comment: Sorry, I see it is nested further. `Try zz.myList.forEach`

Comment: Thank you! This worked. 
I figured out why the above error was thrown,

zz is an instance of MyDataList class, which contains the list named myList.

So
zz.myList.forEach((data) => print(
      "Row contains ${data.SYMBOL} - ${data.FORECAST} - ${data.OPEN} - ${data.CLOSE}"));

Fixed it.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it print what you want by overriding `toString()` in `MyData` class:

```
class MyData {
  ...

  // Add this
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Symbol: $SYMBOL, Open: $OPEN, Close: $CLOSE, Forecast: $FORECAST';
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I access the data inside the MyData instance? I am only using print to learn how to access the data inside the list.

Comment: amugofjava's answer pretty much answers that. He access them through the `data` object from `forEach`.

Comment: Yes, I understood how to access it. Thank you very much.